# SharePoint Get-PnPListItem -Query

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm try to retrieve some data from a SharePoint list with Get-PnPListItem. I'm able to get list items without the -Query parameter but when I try to query certain items in the list I get the error:

Get-PnPListItem : Cannot complete this action.
Please try again.

The line of code is as follows:

```
$items = Get-PnPListItem -List myList -Query "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>TemplateID</Value></Eq</Where></Query></View>"
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Have you connected to site first(Connect-PnPOnline). if you dont mind can put all the Powershell Script. Your query seems ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lost a '>' after `</Eq` in your code, that's not why it doesn't work. Please add it and check if it works.

The correct one:

```
$items = Get-PnPListItem -List myList -Query "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>TemplateID</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
```

Comment: I overlooked that missing '>' I guess. Thanks.